# python : re-use class name

Tags: python, add-on

Simple addon template :

```
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name": "test",
    "author": "me",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": ""
}

class OBJECT_OT_CustomOp(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.test"
    bl_label = "test"

    def execute(self, context):
        
        None
        
        return {'FINISHED'}

addon_keymaps = []

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_CustomOp)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_CustomOp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

My question is about that class name (-> **OBECT_OT_CustomOp**). I just want to know : Whatever name it is , can i really re-use it for other customop/addon ? since i've tried to use that same class name for different op and it doesn't conflict. Everything works fine, because that customop is unregistered when i exit the tool ? But will it break at some point ?

Comment: Hello, why do you want to re-use the name ? Do you enable the add-on in the preferences or do you run it from a scripting editor ?

Comment: From the add-on, install and enable in preference , and it will add item in menu to run a function. Since i think everytime the function is done, it will unregister the class, so then i can reuse it without conflict.  Because i've done it (use for 2 different addon) and there's no conflict or error. There's no purpose of reusing it, It's jut i'm curious because it works.

Comment: "every time the function is done, it will unregister the class"? It will only invoke unregister when user intentionally disable that addon. (Or invoke that method directly)

Comment: sorry , i thought it will be unregistered when i'm done with the function. But if it's unregistered when i disable in preference, then how it come ? the 2 different addons (which share same class name) are ON and they still working without  poblem ? Hoe come ?

Comment: The real case is : i duplicate my addon , modify it as another addon and forgot to change the classname of the 2nd (duplicated) addons, so they use the same classname. I found out later that they share the same classname, but i'm confused because so far , they just works and no conflict. I'm just confused and curious why this happen .

Answer (score 3):

**Same class name is not an issue.**

when a register-able class is registered it is added to `bpy.types` with a name generated from the `bl_idname`.

eg

```
class Foo(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.test"
```

if succesfully registered will be known to blender as the class

```
bpy.types.OBJECT_OT_test
```

*or similarly after running question code in text editor (`__main__` thread)*  The OT stands for "Operator Type", similarly PT and MT are Panels and Menus respectively.

```
>>> bpy.types.OBJECT_OT_test
<class '__main__.OBJECT_OT_CustomOp'>

>>> bpy.ops.object.test.idname()
'OBJECT_OT_test'

>>> bpy.ops.object.test.idname_py()
'object.test'
```

Can also import it as a module from text block, and run the register method. This is, IMO, a better way to test simple addon code in blender as it gives the option to unregister, since the classes are no longer "lost" in the **main** thread.  Find Link

```
>>> myaddon = D.texts['Text'].as_module()
>>> myaddon.register()
>>> bpy.types.OBJECT_OT_test
<class 'Text.OBJECT_OT_CustomOp'>
```

So has now re-registered the operator, this time belonging to the "Text" module.
Having a variable the same name in the scope of its own  module is no issue.  Having another matching `bl_idname` will overwrite the one registered previously.

Would either stick to naming convention and

```
class OBJECT_OT_test(...):
    bl_idname = "object.test"
```

or not at all

```
class TestOperator(...):
    bl_idname = "object.test"
```

whereas feel question's `OBJECT_OT_CustomOp` is some hickly-dy pickle-dy in-between sort or arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

Got a quick test over different situation:

1. register same `class name` same `bl_idname`:

   Blender will overwrite existing operator mapping (`bl_idname` → initiate same python class)
2. register different `class name` with same `bl_idname`:

   Still, Blender overwrites existing operator due to `bl_idname` overwritten, this cause all operators registered before using same `bl_idname` replaced by new one(there should be only one, of course)
3. register same `class name` with different `bl_idname`:

   Blender does not complain about duplicate class name since it works only on `bl_idname`, the new operator with same class name will work concurrently with the previous one. Both can be access by different **`bl_idname`**.

Since the test is done in text editor, each **run** has it's own scope, local name will not affect each other. So you are free to "reuse name".

On the other hand, the `register()` will map a `bl_idname` to an operator class, use that class *object* to do operation when user call an operator. IIRC the object is registered in separated place (RNA meta) and it shouldn't conflict with name either you assign a new operator to original operator.

e.g.

```
#  Code:
import io_mesh_uv_layout  # UV layout exporter ops
io_mesh_uv_layout = OBJECT_OT_add_object  # random ops from template

# Execute UV layout exporter → Original UV export operator
```

Not sure if there is any mistake in this discussion

Comment: The real case is : i duplicate my addon , modify it as another addon and forgot to change the classname of the 2nd (duplicated) addons, so they use the same classname. I found out later that they share the same classname, but i'm confused because so far , they just works and no conflict. I'm just confused and curious why this happen

Comment: how should they break? Unless they share the same python namespace “scope”, same name between two add-on will be fine without knowing they are twins. The register is kind of dictionary key in, although name are same, but the id of python class is different, hence both can work

Comment: `register()` take care of bl_idname inside the given class attribute. It then set an index for that idname with that class object. something like `bl_idnames: dict[bl_idname] = OT_classname_object`. So if the id name doesn’t conflict,this dictionary works great even the name inside it is same(but they are not in general). But as you mention, now I am curious about the class itself: Is the class instance create every time when running an ops? Or there is only one operators per scene(or context). I am afraid I just talk all bullshit about it and misleading readers of this answer