# Unregister Add-On Class That's Registered Earlier

Tags: scripting, add-on

My requirement is to unregister a class before registering a new class with the same `bl_idname`. (As far as I understand `bl_idname` must be unique for each registered class, otherwise blender reports an error saying `bl_idname` is already used.)

If I try to unregister using the class reference, this doesn't work since the context of registration of earlier class was different.

So my question is: is there a way to unregister a class already registered from some other session? (I have the unique `bl_idname`, so maybe unregister using the `bl_idname`?)

Comment: Maybe related ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/202969/86891

Comment: @Gorgious Not really, the referred post discusses the registered class within bpy.types. I need a class reference that can be used to unregister the class from outside.

Comment: Got the solution in the following post:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134416/135191